# Implementing 'Download to Computer' functionality of browser

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, download

I am trying to download a `mp3` file at a given link using `NSURLConnection`. However, I usually get time-out errors. Entering the link into the browser shows the default player, however the music file is not loaded either:

[image: Downloading mp3's is not illegal in all countries]

However, if I create the following simple HTML file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="link_to_the_mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then load the file into Safari, right click on the `Download` link, then select `Download to Computer` (or whathever it's called in English), Safari downloads the file.

Any ideas on how I can implement this in my own app?

---

I tried using

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

and

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *r, NSData *data, NSError *e) { /.../ }];`
```

without success.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I tried `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` (`NSData`) and `-sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` (`NSURLConnection`). Trying your method now...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Looking good so far (doing some testing). Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: done!  I hope this solution works well for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to hit a fly with a sledgehammer, using "`NSURLConnection`".

Try doing something a wee bit more high level such as

[`NSData * mp3data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:options:error: ];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithContentsOfURL%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)

(the added benefit here is that you can get useful errors back via the "`error:`" parameter you pass into the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on what you need to do:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourMp3URLString];
//URL of the mp3 file

NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", mp3Name];
//NSString with the name of the mp3

NSString* destinationPath = [filePathString stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
//NSString with the filePathString (NSString with path destination, you could 
//change it to something like this @"User/Desktop")
//and add the NSString filename to the end of it
//so, if we have like User/Desktop it will become User/Desktop/mp3Name.mp3

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLDownload* download = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[download setDestination:destinationPath allowOverwrite:NO];
//create the URLRequest and Download the mp3 to the destinationPath
```

Comment: Interesting, never knew about this class. Checking it out now.

Comment: I keep getting `kCFURLErrorCannotOpenFile` errors, so for now, I will use Michael's approach.